A confusion regarding a specific high school algebric problem
In this equation, $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{c^2} = \frac{b^2 + c^2}{a^2} = \frac{a^2 + c^2}{b^2} = \frac{1}{k}$$
If we want to find value of k we can calculate algebrically and we would get k=2. But the way we get to this we NEVER assume anything that a,b and c are all real numbers. So it should be applicable for every a, b and c no matter if it's real or not. But for the values like
a^2=1, b^2=1 and c^2=-2 this relation is still satisfied but with these numbers we get k=-1. But how is this even possible? When we derived the solution for K fir random a,b and c we never assumed anything like they need to be real or complex. But for these numbers we get a different value of k . So. What's going on?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To derive $k=1/2$ (hence $a^2=b^2=c^2$), you just need $a^2+b^2+c^2\ne0$. This is not the case in your example $1+1+(-2)$.

@AnneBauval Oh.... that's exactly what I wanted to know....what a silly mistake I was making. Should I delete this question now ow is it okay if it's here??

The equations in $a,b,c$ are equivalent to
$$
(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+c)(a-c)=0,\quad (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b)(a-b)=0.
$$
Either $a=b=c$ up to signs, so that the fractions are $\frac{1}{2}$, or $a^2+b^2+c^2=0$. Here, in the second case, we use that we have real numbers to exclude this, because by assumption $a,b,c$ are nonzero.
Over the complex numbers there are indeed nonzero solutions, where the fractions can be equal to $-1$, because $c^2=-(a^2+b^2)$, and permutations of it.
Edit: The summarise the comments, we can rewrite the conditions by the three equations $(a^2+b^2)k=c^2$, $(a^2+c^2)k=a^2$ and $(a^2+c^2)k=b^2$. Summing up yields
$$
2k(a^2+b^2+c^2)=a^2+b^2+c^2,
$$
This gives
$$
(2k-1)(a^2+b^2+c^2)=0.
$$
Taking the limit of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ to zero does not imply that $2k=1$. In fact, if $a^2+b^2+c^2=0$, then we obtain no condition on $t=2k-1$ because $0\cdot t=0$ always.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
